# Convert PEAR::DB-style DSN into PDO-DSN

Tags: php, sql, pdo, pear, dsn

I am looking for a way how to convert a [PEAR:DB / MDB2-style DSN](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php)

```
phptype://username:password@hostspec/database
```

into format supported by PHP PDO ([such as this mysql case](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php))

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
```

I was looking for some existing implementation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't know of any existing solutions, though it seems this would be a pretty quick fix to roll your own solution as you're dealing with a specific, known format for the source and target strings ... with a regex perhaps.

Comment: @rdlowrey, yeah, that's I had to do. Code supplied below. Would be nice to look at some other implementations as I'm not sure I'm handling all possible formats properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem with this code, but it's not yet properly tested:

```
preg_match('|([a-z]+)://([^:]*)(:(.*))?@([A-Za-z0-9\.-]*)(/([0-9a-zA-Z_/\.]*))|',
     $dsn,$matches);
$dsn=array(
    $matches[1].':host='.$matches[5].';dbname='.$matches[7],
    $matches[2],
    $matches[4]
);
```